# Share Windows 10 share permanently

Tags: windows-10, network-shares, shared-folders

I have shared the Z: drive on a Windows 10 (21H2) system as an administrator. Now I have noticed that a few minutes after the administrator logs out the share is no longer available and when the administrator logs back in the share is automatically made available again.

The following did not work:

```
net config server /autodisconnect:-1
```

The described problem does not occur on a Windows Server 2016.

How to share the share permanently?

Answer (score 0):

The post
[Map a network drive to be used by a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182750/map-a-network-drive-to-be-used-by-a-service)
contains the following
[answer by ForcePush](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4763324/165358),
which I'll partially quote below.

It shows how to create a permanent mapping, but requires elevating
yourself to SYSTEM. You should immediately go out of this mode
after creating the mapping, as staying in it is dangerous.

The answer follows :

> For this hack you will need [SysinternalsSuite by Mark
> Russinovich](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx):
>
> **Step one:** Open an elevated cmd.exe prompt (Run as administrator)
>
> **Step two:** Elevate again to root using PSExec.exe: Navigate to the folder containing SysinternalsSuite and execute the following command
> `psexec -i -s cmd.exe` you are now inside of a prompt that is `nt authority\system` and you can prove this by typing `whoami`. The `-i`
> is needed because drive mappings need to interact with the user
>
> **Step Three:** Create the persistent mapped drive as the SYSTEM account with the following command `net use z: \\servername\sharedfolder /persistent:yes`
>
> It's that easy!
>
> **WARNING**: You can only remove this mapping the same way you created it, from the SYSTEM account. If you need to remove it, follow steps 1
> and 2 but change the command on step 3 to `net use z: /delete`.
>
> **NOTE**: The newly created mapped drive will now appear for ALL users of this system but they will see it displayed as "Disconnected Network
> Drive (Z:)". Do not let the name fool you. It may claim to be
> disconnected but it will work for everyone. That's how you can tell
> this hack is not supported by M$.

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work for me. But thanks for your answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the automatically active power management fixed the problem.